# Count the number of items from a dictionary inside another dictionary in Python

Tags: python

What better way (most elegant) to count the number of items `{'id': n}`?

```
'childs': {
  1: [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}],
  2: [{'id': 4}],
  3: [{'id': 5}, {'id': 6},]
}
```

```
>>> 6
```

Comment: Better than what? What did you first try?

Comment: Is it only two deep, also "more elegant"... more elegant than what? What have you tried already?

Comment: Sorry! Most elegant way. Only with `for` and `len`?

Comment: Your requirements are strictly to use for and len?

Comment: Do you have only elements with {'id': n} as values ?

Comment: I did not want to use `for`. Is there any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should answer to the comments to have a proper answer.

In the meantime, with `d` being the dict, I'd go with:

```
sum(len(x) for x in d['childs'].itervalues())
```

If you don't want to use `for`, you can do:

```
sum(map(len, d['childs'].itervalues()))
```

Or a twisted:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x + len(y), d['childs'].itervalues(), 0)
```

But really the first version is how you would do it. It's classic Python.

Comment: I agree. The first version answered my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood your problem, the main task is to count the total occurrence of key "id" whenever it has value of "n". Here the dictionary name is "Childs".

```
count = 0
for key,value in Childs.iteritems():
    if Childs[key]["id"]:
        count += 1
print count
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

```
myDict = {'childs': {
  1: [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}],
  2: [{'id': 4}],
  3: [{'id': 5}, {'id': 6},]
}}

count = 0
for key in myDict["childs"]:
    for item in myDict["childs"][key]:
        if checkIfItemIsValid(item):
            count += 1

print count
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {
  1: [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}],
  2: [{'id': 4}],
  3: [{'id': 5}, {'id': 6},]
}

sum(len(i) for i in d.itervalues())
# 6
```

But this assumes that every member of that child value list is actually an item you want to count.

Here is one other way without using `for`:

```
sum(map(len, d.itervalues()))
```

In case some items may not have the 'id' key and you are only trying to count those which have that key:

```
sum(1 for obj in i for i in d.itervalues() if 'id' in obj)
```

or

```
len([obj for obj in i for i in d.itervalues() if 'id' in obj])
```

Comment: You can lose the listcomp, no?

Answer (score 0):

```
cat = {1: [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}], 2: [{'id': 4}], 3: [{'id': 5}, {'id': 6},]}
sum(len(x) for x in cat.values())
```